# Have problems with init(roundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:)

Tags: swift2, uibezierpath

I am using swift 2.0, I am trying to make a view's left top corner and bottom left corner rounded, so I used

```
init(roundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:)
```

However, the result is strange, only the left top corner is rounded, the bottom left corner is not working.

here is my code:

```
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.statusView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.TopLeft , UIRectCorner.BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)).CGPath
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = maskPath
    maskLayer.frame = cell.statusView.frame
    cell.statusView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

here is the result[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I found my own mistake, the problems comes out from the frame and bounds, just change

```
maskLayer.frame = cell.statusView.frame
```

into

```
maskLayer.frame = cell.statusView.bounds
```